# Coloring a transparent black/white image

Tags: layers, transparency, paint.net

Given a black and white image like lips, how would I get those in red?

[image: Lips]

I don't want to use global flood filling, because that may not consider alpha transparency correcly.

How would I do that with layers?

No matter what I tried, the transparency is always lost. Paint.NET answers only, please.

[image]

Comment: You may find that there are only very few paint.net users here. Apparenty you need alphamask plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust Curves. Use it in RGB mode.

[image]

The tool allows you to adjust R,G and B separately or together. I removed the selection check from G anB and lifted only red. You can turn black to any combination of R, G and B by changing the place of the checkmark.

Comment: Oh dear, even without any layers! Thanks.

Comment: Consider this only as a quick trick. It's useless if you want to insert easily more than one color. Your own  answer doesn't have that limitation. It can be your basic tool to work around the lack of layer masks.

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible with [BoltBait's Paste Alpha](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/113220-boltbaits-plugin-pack-for-pdn-v4212-and-beyond-updated-july-16-2020/) plugin.

1. Copy the transparent PNG to the clipboard
2. Create a completely red layer
3. Go To Effect / Object / Paste Alpha
4. From the second dropdown, choose "Alpha channel on clipboard".

[image: BoltBait's Paste Alpha]